# Unable to select tabs using mouse in the latest angular-ui-bootstrap version

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I upgraded the angular-ui-bootstrap version to 2.2.0. That is affecting the uib-tabs behavior. I am unable to select a tab using mouse click but the same behavior works fine when i try to navigate and select using keyboard. The code that I have written to implement the tabs is as follows:

```
<uib-tabset active="active" class="tabs-flat">
    <uib-tab index="0" active="states['alert-details.overview']">
      <uib-tab-heading><a ui-sref="alert-details.overview" translate class="tab-head">Overview</a></uib-tab-heading>
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1" active="states['alert-details.history']">
      <uib-tab-heading><a ui-sref="alert-details.history" translate class="tab-head">History</a></uib-tab-heading>
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2" active="states['alert-details.trigger']">
      <uib-tab-heading><a ui-sref="alert-details.trigger" translate class="tab-head">Trigger Events</a></uib-tab-heading>
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="3" active="states['alert-details.all-fields']">
      <uib-tab-heading><a ui-sref="alert-details.all-fields" translate class="tab-head">All Alert Fields</a></uib-tab-heading>
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
```

Do I need to add any settings pertaining to mouse-click. This is plunker link if that helps to better understand the problem.
https://plnkr.co/edit/PVrqPEaR9h380gtiR3Uv?p=preview
 Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tabs work (chrome 54), but not when clicking straight on the anchor links, use are not defining them correctly, refer to the documentation.

What you should do is..

1. remove the anchor links, ui-tabs were not designed to work with `<a>` tags
2. `active` should only be on `uib-tabset`
3. you can use the `select` attribute to run an expression when a specific tab is selected (either by clicking the tab body or the text)

> select() $ - An optional expression called when tab is activated. Supports $event in template for expression.

4. run your state change inside a callback that the expression will refer to or as an inline expression on your markup

   ```
   <uib-tabset class="tabs-flat" active="selectedIndex">
       <uib-tab index="0" select="$state.go('alert-details.overview')">
           <uib-tab-heading>
               Overview
           </uib-tab-heading>
       </uib-tab>
   ....
   </uib-tabset
   ```